# Python package not available from current channel

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

When I want to install jupyter notebook or spyder in one of my environments I encountered this error:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- python=3.1

Current channels:

- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Why would this happen?

Edit:
I created the environment with scikit-learn, pytorch, and torchvision without specifying any version. After creating the environment, I tried installing spyder using both commands:

```
conda install spyder
conda install -c anaconda spyder
```

Neither worked.
It seems that the environment automatically used python=3.1 when I created it.

Edit:
When I put everything in one env.yml file instead of the command line it seems to work. Not sure why.

Comment: Can you please show *how* you are trying to install this? Specifically, how do you specify the version number?

Answer (score 5):

I've ran into the similar issue with my configuration:

```
$ conda -V
conda 4.10.3
$ python -V
Python 3.10.0
```

I see there is an issue that conda truncated Python version to one digit of the minor version (this would work for last 13 years since python 3.0 was released :-)) and there is a merged pull request fixing this issue: https://github.com/conda/conda/pull/10970/commits
in conda 4.11

So, we just need to get that version of conda :)

It is not yet available at https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html, but has been available in the repo: https://github.com/conda/conda/releases/tag/4.11.0 since two weeks.

Comment: I just ran `conda update conda` which now updated to `conda-4.11.0` and the error with "`python 3.1`" is gone from my system.

Answer (score 4):

You are specifying python 3.1, which is long dead and therefore not available from any channels. You probably wanted to have the latest, which is 3.**10**, so you would need to specify it like that:

```
conda install -c conda-forge python=3.10
```

Note though that installing python 3.10 will not enable you (at the time of writing) to install jupyter and spyder. On my windows machine, qt dependencies cannot be matched. Possibly because no python 3.10 packages are available yet.
I would suggest to just create the env specifying `jupyter` and `spyder` and have conda decide the latest available version:

```
conda create -n newEnv -c conda-forge jupyter spyder
```

Currently, that would be python 3.9.7

Comment: My intent is not to install both, but to install at least one of them in my newly created environment. It seems conda decided the latest available version of python I could have with sklearn, PyTorch, and torchvision is 3.1.

Comment: try specifying everything on the command line when creating the environment. E.g. `conda create -c conda-forge -c pytorch -n newEnv jupyter scikit-learn pytorch torchvision`

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new environment, without adding any packages, install spyder, and then install any packages, you want.

That worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).